# How can I use a p-iris/autoiris lens on a camera without a connection port?

Tags: electrical-engineering

My team owns a Point Grey camera that we need to attach a wide angle lens to. The wide angle lens we have has a cable allowing for autoiris and p-iris control, but the camera doesn't have the autoiris/p-iris port. Is there another way to connect the iris controller? Can we get away with not using it at all?

Comment: You might have better luck on photography.se

Comment: It depends on whether you need the iris to be adjustable, and how variable the lighting conditions are, and whether the lens iris can be adjusted without camera control. At the moment there is far too little information here to answer the question.

Comment: Hi Johnny, welcome to Engineering SE. I agree that this is a question for [our site for photography experts and enthusiasts](http://photo.stackexchange.com/). I or another moderator can move this to the correct site, if you add some details along the lines of @Andy's comment asking for more information. You can [edit] your post or, if you prefer, leave this one alone and start a new one on Photography (keeping in mind more information may be needed).